# Codeigniter Form Does Not Post Inline Javascript to Controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Hi i am submitting my Codeignitor form to controller. Submitted data contain inline javascript with html code which i want to save into the database. But when i check the code after submitting then i realize that inline javascript is not there with the html code. e.g

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="myFunction();">Click Me!</a>here is a paragraph again!</p>
```

after submitting it becomes like,

```
<p><a href="#" >Click Me!</a>here is a paragraph again!</p>
```

i am using codeigniter standard method to post a form like

```
<?php
    $attributes = array('target' => '_blank', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'); 
    echo form_open('controller/method',$attributes); 
    ?>
```

One more thing when i disable X-XS-Protection then it is working fine but i think it is a security issue. Any help would be very appreciative

Comment: what do you want to get after the submit

Comment: Inline Javascript which is missing after submitting of the form

Comment: did you mean onClick="myFunction()"

Comment: Yes OnClick and other methods like this